# Cloning a flutter project from github with vs code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, flutter

I'm working a school project using Flutter and we need to use a version control system such as git.

For that reason I've done the following:

1. I created a flutter project using VS Code as the Flutter
   documentation explained.
2. I pushed the created project to my Github repo without changing
   anything, including the .gitignore file.
3. I tried cloning the project from another computer using VS Code as
   well (We have no intention on using Android Studio or any other IDE
   for that matter).
4. Once the project was cloned into the new workspace, I ran **flutter
   packages get** to install the missing packages (ignored from the first
   push to the repo).
5. Now VS Code is telling me that I need to push the **pubspec.lock**
   file created by the previous command.

My questions are:

- Isn't the lock file supposed to be ignored? (it doesn't exist in the
  .gitignore file by default)
- Are the steps I made the correct ones for a flutter project?

This is the default .gitignore file contents:

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/
# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# Visual Studio Code related
.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# Exceptions to above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
```

Comment: Can you post the `.gitignore`

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon I editted question

Comment: I'm not familiar with flutter but you probably want to ignore lock files. Add `*.lock` in the misc section. If you already committed the lock file you'll need to `git rm -r --cached .` Then add everything back `git add .`

Comment: Every flutter project repo, I came across does have pubspec.lock. Even my all flutter projects has pubspec.lock in repos. Why do you want to add it in gitignore?

Comment: @TirthPatel I'm working with a team and each member has to clone the project and run the `flutter packages get`command to install the app packages, the command also creates the `pubspec.lock` file. And since it's newly created in each local repo, it must be pushed, which is redundant knowing that it always contains the same information about the project.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't the lock file supposed to be ignored? (it doesn't exist in the .gitignore file by default)

The pubspec.lock file isn't ignored by default. If pubspec.lock isn't included in the cloned project, you can generate a new one by running `flutter pub get`.

> Are the steps I made the correct ones for a flutter project?

The steps from 1 to 4 seem to be fine until there's a conflict requiring for pubspec.lock to be pushed. The project's pubspec.lock seems to be tracked and has been committed to the repository. I recommend keeping the pubspec.lock file in the repo since it ensures that different checkouts will use the same versions of dependencies.